# SSDT Unit Testing with Database Variables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools, ssdt-2019

I have a database project in Visual Studio 2019 that references another database.  I have added a dacpac and use a variable to reference that database.

This works great, until it comes to unit tests.  I have added a unit test project, but the Unit Test project doesn't perform the variable substitution - it says the object [$(db)]... is undefined.

How can I unit test with database variables?

Comment: Use synonyms for all remote objects, SSDT "doesn't like 3-4 part names"

Comment: Side question: Why do you need the variables, and not just use the database names as literals?